# automatic content change react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intervals

I have a problem with the automatic content change. After 7 seconds it should change automatically by 1 (and so it works). The problem is that when the user clicks on the first card, after the carousel automatically goes to the second card, the interval, which is already running, completes its cycle and increases the index, causing the carousel to jump to the third card, not the the second etc.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      const nextIndex = (activeIndex + 1) % expertise.length;
      setActiveIndex(nextIndex);
      ;
    }, 7000);
  
    return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  }, [activeIndex]);
  
  const handleCardClick = (index) => {
    setActiveIndex(index);
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  };
```

I would like to see it work this way. If the content automatically changes to, for example, the fourth card, and the user then changes to the first, then after 7 seconds it should change to the second, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [the functional form of `setState`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state) so your captured `activeIndex` reference isn't stale.

```
setActiveIndex(activeIndex => (activeIndex + 1) % expertise.length);
```

Comment: this solve a problem, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
  // This function both initializes, and then at any time resets, the
  // interval that causes the periodic setting of cards
  const resetInterval = ()=>{
    if(intervalRef.current){
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    }
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      const nextIndex = (activeIndex + 1) % expertise.length;
      setActiveIndex(nextIndex);
      ;
    }, 7000);
  }

  // whenever the currently active index changes, 
  // we clear the exististing interval and set a new one
  useEffect(() => {
    resetInterval()
  
    return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  }, [activeIndex]);
  
  // whenever the user interacts we clear the existing interval and
  // set a new one.
  const handleCardClick = (index) => {
    setActiveIndex(index);
    resetInterval()
  };
```

Whenever a user clicks a card, you can clear the interval and start it again. That way it will always be a full 7 seconds between every card change. I think that was your problem?

The other interpretation i can see of your question is that you are having trouble synchronizing the active index variable. I don't think that you should have an issue with the code above, I think it should stay synced, but if you are having trouble you could start using a ref to track the current index:

If you do this, the interval handler will always know what the active index is.

```
  const currentIndexRef = React.useRef(activeIndex)
  currentIndexRef.current = activeIndex;


  const resetInterval = ()=>{
    if(intervalRef.current){
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    }
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      const nextIndex = (currentIndexRef.current + 1) % expertise.length;
      setActiveIndex(nextIndex);
      ;
    }, 7000);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    resetInterval()
  
    return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  }, [activeIndex]);
  
  const handleCardClick = (index) => {
    setActiveIndex(index);
    resetInterval()
  };
```

Comment: ll the time there is the same problem. after the carousel automatically goes to the second card, the interval, which is already running, completes its cycle and increases the index, so if at that time the user changes to another card, the interval resets, but goes after 7 seconds to the third card, even if the user changes to the fifth card

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the interval whenever the user manually changes the card. This can be done by clearing the existing interval and setting a new one each time the active index changes, whether automatically or manually

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Function to start the interval
  const startInterval = () => {
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      const nextIndex = (activeIndex + 1) % expertise.length;
      setActiveIndex(nextIndex);
    }, 7000);
  };

  // Start the interval
  startInterval();

  // Clear interval on cleanup
  return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
}, [activeIndex]); // Dependency on activeIndex

const handleCardClick = (index) => {
  setActiveIndex(index);
  // Clear and restart the interval whenever a card is clicked
  clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  startInterval(); // You need to define this function inside the useEffect
};
```

Comment: interval resets fine, but does not "assign" itself to the card selected by the user